# Place TextView created in code, under TextView in XML

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I have searched high and low but can't get this to work.

```
            TextView topic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic);
        topic.setText(json_data.getString("topic"));


        TextView poster = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
        poster.setText(json_data.getString("name"));

        TextView detail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
        detail.setText(json_data.getString("detail"));

        TextView test = new TextView(this);
        test.setText("test string");
        test.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.detail);

        addContentView(test, p);
```

Everything works, other than the last textview (test) which will only show in top left.  I want it under the textview (detail).
XML is based on

suedo code.

Any help would be truly appreciated as this is the last bit of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `test.setLayoutParams(p);` as such:

```
    RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newlayout, null, false);

    setContentView(yourLayout);

    TextView topic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic);
    topic.setText(json_data.getString("topic"));


    TextView poster = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    poster.setText(json_data.getString("name"));

    TextView detail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
    detail.setText(json_data.getString("detail"));

    TextView test = new TextView(this);
    test.setText("test string");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.detail);

    test.setLayoutParams(p);

    yourLayout.addView(test);

    setContentView(yourLayout);
```

Comment: thank you spoon thumb, that is bang on. Thanks i can see where i went wrong. And thanks again.